# why Angular schema form custom validation message is always Field does not validate?

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

I have the following:

```
vm.schema = {
  type: 'object',
  title: 'Account',
  properties: {
    username: {
      type: 'string',
      title: 'Username'
    }
  },
  required: ['username']
}

vm.form = [
  'username'
]

vm.submit = function() {
  $scope.$broadcast 'schemaFormValidate'

  $http.post('a link', vm.model).then(function(data) {
    // somecode
  }, function(response) {
    $scope.$broadcast(
      'schemaForm.error.' + response.data.errors[0].key,
      response.data.errors[0].errorCode,
      response.data.errors[0].message
    );
  });
}
```

so errors are detected from the server-side and the problem here is that I always get the error message as the following: **Field does not validate**

Answer (score 0):

Add `"validationMessage" : "some message"`

to schema to override default message.